# Definir variável como null em uma Query no php

Tags: php, mysql, query, null

Tenho a seguinte QUERY no meu sistema:

```
$Query = "SELECT * FROM Monit WHERE
    ($Modulo IS NULL OR Modulo = '$Modulo') AND 
    ($Usuario IS NULL OR Usuario = '$Usuario') AND
    ($Data IS NULL OR Data_reg = '$Data') 
    ORDER BY Data_monit DESC LIMIT 0,10";
    $execute = mysqli_query($conexao, $Query);

    while($line = mysqli_fetch_array($execute)){
        echo $line['Modulo'];
    }
```

Para fazer os teste se ela funcionaria quando entrasse algum valor *NULL* defini as variáveis com estes valores:

```
$Modulo = "NULL";
$Usuario = "NULL";
$Data = "NULL";
```

E funciona perfeitamente desta forma.
Porém, se defino as entradas dessa forma:

```
$Modulo = "NULL";
$Usuario = "roberto";
$Data = "NULL";
```

Não funciona pq fica faltando as aspas simples *' '*
Se coloco dessa forma:

```
$Modulo = "NULL";
$Usuario = "'roberto'";
$Data = "NULL";
```

A query não funciona, e se adiciono as aspas simples direto na query:

```
$Query = "SELECT * FROM Monit WHERE
    ($Modulo IS NULL OR Modulo = '$Modulo') AND 
    ('$Usuario' IS NULL OR Usuario = '$Usuario') AND
    ($Data IS NULL OR Data_reg = '$Data') 
    ORDER BY Data_monit DESC LIMIT 0,10";
    $execute = mysqli_query($conexao, $Query);

    while($line = mysqli_fetch_array($execute)){
        echo $line['Modulo'];
    }
```

Funcionará, porém, se retornar o valor NULL nas variáveis não retornará nada;
Não sei se ficou muito claro, mas basicamente não sei como definir as variaveis que estarão na query como nulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se é uma solução muito elegante mas você pode validar se a variável está preenchida antes de montar a *query* e manter as *aspas simples*:

```
if($Modulo == NULL) $Modulo = '';
if($Usuario == NULL) $Usuario = '';
if($Data == NULL) $Data = '';

$Query = "SELECT * FROM Monit WHERE
    ($Modulo = '' OR Modulo = '$Modulo') AND 
    ($Usuario = '' OR Usuario = '$Usuario') AND
    ($Data = '' OR Data_reg = '$Data') 
    ORDER BY Data_monit DESC LIMIT 0,10";
    $execute = mysqli_query($conexao, $Query);
```

Comment: Então eu mantenho as aspas simples nas variáveis  antes do IS NULL?

Comment: Foi mal, @Shinchila_Matadora, removi; veja se resolveu

Comment: Valeu @rLinhares, só tive que colocar as aspas nas variáveis mas a logica funcionou :D